# chartobject-1.render() Error >> Unable to find the container DOM element. Vue.js + FusionCharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fusioncharts

I'm trying to use FusionCharts in my Vue.js project. I keep getting this error every time I try to render the charts in my components. This is a code of one of the components:

```
<template>
  <div class="highlights-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 border-top">
    <div id="fusion-uv">
      <fusioncharts
        :type="type"
        :width="width"
        :height="height"
        :containerbackgroundopacity="containerbackgroundopacity"
        :dataformat="dataFormat"
        :dataSource="dataSource"
      ></fusioncharts>
      <p class="card-value mt-4">{{ highlights.uvIndex }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </template>
 
 <script>
 export default {
  props: ["highlights"],
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      type: "angulargauge",
      renderAt: "fusion-uv",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      containerbackgroundopacity: 0,
      dataFormat: "json",
      dataSource: {
        chart: {
          caption: "UV Index",
          captionFontBold: "0",
          captionFontColor: "#000000",
          captionPadding: "30",
          lowerLimit: "0",
          upperLimit: "15",
          lowerLimitDisplay: "1",
          upperLimitDisplay: "1",
          showValue: "0",
          theme: "fusion",
          baseFont: "Roboto",
          bgAlpha: "0",
          canvasbgAlpha: "0",
          gaugeInnerRadius: "75",
          gaugeOuterRadius: "110",
          pivotRadius: "0",
          pivotFillAlpha: "0",
          valueFontSize: "20",
          valueFontColor: "#000000",
          valueFontBold: "1",
          tickValueDistance: "3",
          autoAlignTickValues: "1",
          majorTMAlpha: "20",
          chartTopMargin: "30",
          chartBottomMargin: "40"
        },
        colorrange: {
          color: [
            {
              minvalue: "0",
              maxvalue: this.highlights.uvIndex.toString(),
              code: "#7DA9E0"
            },
            {
              minvalue: this.highlights.uvIndex.toString(),
              maxvalue: "15",
              code: "#D8EDFF"
            }
          ]
        },
        annotations: {
          groups: [
            {
              items: [
                {
                  id: "val-label",
                  type: "text",
                  text: this.highlights.uvIndex.toString(),
                  fontSize: "20",
                  font: "Source Sans Pro",
                  fontBold: "1",
                  fillcolor: "#212529",
                  x: "$gaugeCenterX",
                  y: "$gaugeCenterY"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        dials: {
          dial: [
            {
              value: this.highlights.uvIndex.toString(),
              baseWidth: "0",
              radius: "0",
              borderThickness: "0",
              baseRadius: "0"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {},
  watch: {
    highlights: {
      handler: function() {
        this.dataSource.colorrange.color[0].maxvalue = this.highlights.uvIndex.toString();
        this.dataSource.colorrange.color[1].minvalue = this.highlights.uvIndex.toString();
        this.dataSource.annotations.groups[0].items[0].text = this.highlights.uvIndex.toString();
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
 };
 </script>
```

That component is later inherited by two higher-level ones and then passed to the main App.vue.

The thing is, that the DOM object (div with id "fusion-uv") is actually rendered and accessible later from console in devtools (document.getElementById).

I already tried several options from stackoverflow and docs including:

- moving the template/script part
- addind renderAt property
- working with container divs (different naming and positions)

Versions of used libs:

```
"fusioncharts": "^3.19.0",
"vue": "^2.5.11",
"vue-fusioncharts": "^3.2.0",
```

What I think that may cause the problem is that the Chart's script runs before the DOM is rendered and that's why it throws an error?

Comment: can you share the vue & vue-fusioncharts versions?

Comment: Already added in original post

Comment: sorry missed it since you are using vue 2, please downgrade vue-fusioncharts to 3.1.0 this will fix the problem, for vue3 you can use vue-fusioncharts 3.2.0

Comment: Thank you! Such simple thing fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Zapdos13 in comments, when you are using Vue2 downgrading vue-fusioncharts in npm to v3.1.0 fixes the problem

Comment: Thanks! Downgrading to 3.1 fixed my problem with Vue2!